# Ansible loop with multiple register value

Tags: automation, ansible

would you please help me with this problem:
I have a playbook with multiple tasks and each tasks contains loop and  register for the output of the task. Last task is going to use lineinfile to create a csv report based on the previous registers. something like below:

```
- name: information
  module:
     xxxx: xxxx
     xxxx: xxxxx
  loop:
  -  xxxx
  -  xxxx
  register: task1_info
- name: information
  module:
     xxxx: xxxx
     xxxx: xxxxx
  loop:
  -  xxxx
  -  xxxx
  register: task2_info
- name: information
  lineinfile:
     path: xxxx
     line: "{{ item.tags.Name }}, {{ item.lastName }}"
  loop:
  -  task1_info.results
  -  task2_info.results
```

if i use only one register at the end it is working, but not loop through all registers. the other option is to write a task after each register which I don't think reasonable!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand your use case that you like to append one list to an other or to merge two lists.

To do so you could use an approach like

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    LIST_1:
      - 1
      - 2
      - 3

    LIST_2:
      - A
      - B
      - C

  tasks:

  - name: Info
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ LIST_1 + LIST_2 }}"
    loop_control:
      extended: true
      label: "{{ansible_loop.index0 }}"
```

resulting into an output of

```
TASK [Info] ******************
ok: [localhost] => (item=0) =>
  msg: 1
ok: [localhost] => (item=1) =>
  msg: 2
ok: [localhost] => (item=2) =>
  msg: 3
ok: [localhost] => (item=3) =>
  msg: A
ok: [localhost] => (item=4) =>
  msg: B
ok: [localhost] => (item=5) =>
  msg: C
```

**Credits to**

- [Append list variable to another list in Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31045409/6771046)

**Further Q&A**

- [Combine two lists in Ansible when one list could be empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62830634/)
- [Ansible: Merge two lists based on an attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55832008/)